# ace:dataTable - Clear selection in rowSelectListener

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm using a `ace:dataTable` to display a list. When the user clicks a row, a detail popup is shown. What I'm trying to achieve is that the click has no effect on the selection of rows.

This is my code:

```
public void rowSelected(SelectEvent event) {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)event.getComponent();
    dataTable.getStateMap().setAllSelected(false);

    // Show Popup etc

    // Prints an empty list
    System.out.println(dataTable.getStateMap().getSelected());
}
```

The popup is shown, but the selection ist still there. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ace:dialog id="dialogid"
    header="Header" widgetVar="nodeDialog"
    modal="true" draggable="false" showEffect="true" hideEffect="true"
    relativePosition="center center">
   ---dialog contnent---
</ace:dialog>

public void rowSelected(SelectEvent event) {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)event.getComponent();
    dataTable.getStateMap().setAllSelected(false);
    // Show Popup etc
    JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(facesContext(), "nodeDialog.show();");
    // Prints an empty list
    ---writwe to the dialog  contnent---
    System.out.println(dataTable.getStateMap().getSelected());
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative approach but doesn't answer my question. Thank you anyway.